# Please explain this error - when using sqldf

Tags: r, traceback

I've found similar questions and errors but none seem to answer mine...

I'm using this code:

```
returns2017 <- sqldf('select c.*, s.cell_no from cis10_2 c inner join selpar17 s on c.regx = s.lower_region2 and c.lower_size between s.lower_size and s.upper_size and c.SIC2007 between s.lower_class2 and s.upper_class2')
```

which I have adapted from a working code with minimal adjustments

it returns the error:

```
 Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'as.labelled' of mode 'function' was not found
```

when I use traceback() I get:

```
5: get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir)
4: match.fun(asfn)
3: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
2: lapply(seq_along(rs), auto)
1: sqldf("select c.*, s.cell_no from cis10_2 c inner join selpar17 s on c.regx = s.lower_region2 and c.lower_size between s.lower_size and s.upper_size and c.SIC2007 between s.lower_class2 and s.upper_class2")
```

Can someone please explain what this error message is saying so I can pick out what is wrong with my statement?

Comment: It is difficult to know for sure without a reproducible example but perhaps you are using a column of class `labelled` and it is trying to convert the result back to that but there is no `as.labelled` function to do that.  Use `sqldf(..., method = "raw")` to turn this off or else define `as.labelled`.

Comment: What are the data types of variables you are using in the `between` conditions?

Comment: That fixed it, thank you. I take it that method="raw" inputs the data in whatever class it came out as, rather than trying to replicate the class it went in as?

Comment: Yes, `method = "raw"` gives the result as it came from the database with the additional processing that sqldf otherwise does.